# Why does Google calendar have multiple ID's for the same calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using the following google API.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list?apix_params=%7B%22showDeleted%22%3Afalse%2C%22showHidden%22%3Atrue%7D

When execute the api request from the browser and provide authorization. I see a long list of calendar#calendarListEntry.

When I go into the console, I only have 4 calendars.

I do not have any selected as hidden. Why is this list longer than what I can see in my console?

Some of the entries seem to be duplicates. For example, if I go to the console, take the ID in the Json, put it into the add calendar field. The calendar shows up in my console. If I delete it, it will still show up in the api query by not the console. If I add it again using the ID it shows up again.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code including the authorization method you are using

Comment: As @DaImTo has said, please provide more information about how you are authorizing the requests. Also it would be great if you could share the output and an example of what is that you are finding odd.